# How to repair this scratch in laminated countertop?

Tags: repair, countertops, laminate, scratches

I made a silly mistake and scratched the countertop of my kitchen.

Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: you mean normal frying oil?

Answer (score 2):

Short of replacement, I don't think there is much you can do to completely hide the scratch.

You might be able to make it less noticeable by coloring it a darker shade so it doesn't stand out as much. The simplest example would be to draw in the scratch with a thin brown marker, although since this is a kitchen you might consider a food safe dye of some sort (they do make non-toxic permanent markers).

Comment: Brown, grey, some sort of matching color. (The picture looks like it's more grey than brown, to me - OP needs to pick the appropriate colors.) Otherwise, 100%. :)